# DNN Web API is not getting parameter

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I created a Web API in DNN with sample provided in 
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/142400/getting-started-with-services-framework-webapi-edition
with this example i modified HelloWorld method for getting  parameter, but not able to get parameter in action while passing through ajax . here is my code

```
public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
{
    public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
    {
        mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute(
            moduleFolderName: "MyServices",
            routeName: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "MyServices" }
        );
    }
}

public class WelcomeController : DnnApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public string HelloWorld(WelcomeParameter id)
    {
        return "test" + id.UserID + id.ClientID + id.LanguageID;
    }
}
public class WelcomeParameter
{
    public int UserID;
    public int ClientID;
    public int LanguageID;
}   

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "desktopmodules/myservices/apI/Welcome/HelloWorld/",
        data: JSON.stringify({"id":{ "UserID": 1, "ClientID": 1, "LanguageID": 1}}),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (msg) {
        alert("Content: " + msg);
    });
 });
</script>
```

This action is not returning output as

> test111

test111

Comment: HTTP GET cannot contains data unless they are in query string. Otherwise, you might want to try HTTP POST.

Comment: @Win i m getting error as 
**405 Method Not Allowed "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."**

Answer (score 0):

> i m getting error as 405 Method Not Allowed "The requested resource
>   does not support http method 'POST'."

You want to add action method with HTTP POST too.

```
public class WelcomeController : DnnApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "";
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public string HelloWorld(WelcomeParameter id)
    {
        return "test" + id.UserID + id.ClientID + id.LanguageID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you change `method: "GET"` to `method: "POST"`?